# HDRI Environment lighting issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-fiber

```
{scene ? (
          <Environment background={true} files={"/Environment/sunflowers_puresky_2k.hdr"} />
        ) : (
        <Environment background={true} files={"/Environment/kloppenheim_07_puresky_2k.hdr"} />
        )
        }
```

I am using a scene changer for day and sunset, now the issue with the sunset hdri is the lighting is getting a little lower, any way i can increase the light?

the light of the first hdri is perfect, so not sure what should I do?

Here's the link for you to try: https://landau-alure-232.vercel.app/

Comment: <Environment background={true} files={"/Environment/kloppenheim_07_puresky_2k.hdr"} backgroundIntensity={1}/>

I tried adding this as gpt suggested, but nothing happens